# Is it possible to to use sandbox without having paypal account?

Tags: paypal

I am beginner php Programmer, i am creating a shopping cart application, I have already created  **Sandbox** Seller and buyer A/c  I jst want to know is  it possible to show the demo of "payment" to client without creating (having paypal credentials of client's A/c) paypal A/c.

Comment: You can use mocking. Try this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244949/mocking-php-functions-in-unit-tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show demo up to the page redirects to PayPal sandbox, but you have to have PayPal buyer account to do some transaction.

You can keep logged into PayPal sandbox account earlier and while the page redirecting to PayPal page then it will automatically show the payment section by skipping login pages.